# Rails 5 ActionCable Render Partial With Logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a partial (called: voting_post) that gets executed when broadcasting, but the ruby logic in it does not evaluated. Here is the partial:

```
<% if current_user && (current_user.id != post.user_id) %>
    <% if current_user.voted_on?(post) %>
        Voted
    <% else %>
        <a href="#" class="vote-up" data-post-id="<%= post.id %>">Vote</a>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Basically the first 'if' statement is such that except the author of the post, everyone else logged in can vote. 
The second 'if' statement checks if the user has already voted.

The terminal log shows this:

```
Rendered posts/_voting_post.html.erb (50.9ms)
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to posts: {:action=>"voteUp", :data=>”        
Voted"}
PostChannel transmitting {"action"=>"voteUp", "data"=>"        
Voted"} (via streamed from posts)
```

So no matter the user scenario, the resulting view as updated by the broadcast, always shows "Voted" even if the user has not voted. Any help in getting this resolved will be appreciated.

Update:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    acts_as_voter
    ...
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user 
    acts_as_voteable
end
```

Update 2:
In my PostChannel I have the following:

```
def vote_up(params)
    post = Post.find(params['id'])
    if post.user_id != current_user.id
        current_user.vote_for(post)
        ActionCable.server.broadcast 'posts', action: 'voteUp', data: render_message(post)
    end
end

private
def render_message(post)
    ApplicationController.render(
        partial: 'posts/voting_post',
        locals: { post: post, current_user: current_user }
    )
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the user model? Or wherever it is that you declared `voted_on?`

Comment: @JaimeRodas I am using [thumbs_up gem](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up). Checkout the update.

Comment: Can you show the PostsController?

Comment: @moveson, The logic regarding the voting is in the related channel file. I posted it in Update 2 above.